# LinkedIn-J does not return educations

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am using LinkedIn-J. My application authenticates without problem, I get data from the user - even their first name, last name etc.

```
Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
profile.getFirstName();
```

However, when I try to get the list of educations, the `Educations` object returned is `null`:

```
Educations educations = profile.getEducations();
educations == null
```

What can be the error? Should my application ask for special permissions to be granted?

Comment: Sorry, a bit off topic, but I find it strange that the library uses `Educations`

Comment: what should it return if they don't have any educations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used the Linkedin-j api before, but according to the LinkedIn api you get firstname, lastname, headline, and some url by default.

So I believe you need to specify that you want education returned. I don't know how to do that in LinkedIn-J though.

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api

For example, with the rest api you'd use this uri:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=12345:(first-name,last-name, educations)
```

Using the LinkedIn J library, it seems like you have to add profile fields using  Set as a parameter to one of their many methods in the client.

Example of a method you could call of many (if you have a connected user):

```
public Person getProfileForCurrentUser(Set<ProfileField> profileFields)
```

ProfileField is an Enum located here:

```
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.enumeration.ProfileField;
```